# Проверить есть ли такое значение в бд через PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Есть скрипт проверки заполнения полей, в mysql все работает решил воспользоваться современным стандартом PDO выдает ошибку
вот скрипт`

```html
    $query = $pdo->getRow("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE tel=?n",$_POST['telephone']);

    if ($query->fetch(0 > 0))
```

помогите разобраться`

Comment: У вас столько непонятной каши, что даже сложно понять откуда вы всё это взяли, на каких просторах неверленда

Comment: Вместо просьбы разобраться в вашем "коде" (который **не может** работать в силу объективных причин) четко сформулируйте изначальную проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум - `$query->fetch(0 > 0)`. Вы в функцию в `fetch` передаете значение которое равно `false`, и проверка выходит `if($query->fetch(false))...`

В PDO нет метода getRow(). есть методы `prepare()` `execute()` и например `fetchAll()`

- с помощью `prepare()` описываете запрос
- с помощью `execute()` выполняете запрос добавляя телефон
- с помощью `fetchAll()` получаете все что найдет запрос.

Пример:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE tel=:telephone");
$query->execute(array(':telephone' => $_POST['telephone']));
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: но в браузере ошибка Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method PDO::getRow() in <b>/home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/saratov/registration/add_field_ajax.php</b> on line <b>39</b><br /> а 39 строка это
 $query = $pdo->getRow("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE tel=?n",$_POST['telephone']); помогите разобраться

Comment: @Koly не удивительно. потому что у PDO нет такого метода. Откуда вы его взяли?

Comment: пробовал подставлять query и prepare тоже ошибки выдает

Comment: раньше делал так и все работало $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE tel='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telephone'])."'"); 

if(mysql_result($query, 0) > 0)

Comment: там одна лишняя скобка была исправил    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE tel=:telephone");
    $query->execute(array(':telephone' => $_POST['telephone']));
    $result = $query->fetchAll(); но все же выдает ошибку

Comment: вот ошибка<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'' in /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/saratov/registration/add_field_ajax.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 /home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/saratov/registration/add_field_ajax.php(40): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/a0031620/domains/yourdosug.ru/public_html/saratov/registration/add_field_ajax.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />